# jest.mock module factory function invocation

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs, node-modules

Given two simple modules with the following implementation:

**bar.js**

```js
export function bar() {
  return 1;
}
```

**foo.js**

```js
import { bar } from './bar';

export function foo() {
  return bar();
}
```

and the test **foo.spec.js**:

```js
import { foo } from './foo';
import { bar } from './bar';

jest.mock('./bar', () => ({
  bar: jest.fn(),
}));

describe('Testing blahblah', () => {
  it('blahblah should call blah', () => {
    foo();
    expect(bar).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

As you may notice the mock of `bar` module defined with module factory function.

**When is this factory function called and how many times?**

Somehow I was under impression that module factory function is called *on each import* and therefore the mock that is returned from the import inside `foo.js` is not the same mock that is returned from the import inside `foo.spec.js`, which should have made the test fail.
I would normally solve it like this:

```js
mockBar = jest.fn();

import { foo } from './foo';
import { bar } from './bar';

jest.mock('./bar', () => ({
  bar: mockBar,
}));

describe('Testing blahblah', () => {
  it('blahblah should call blah', () => {
    foo();
    expect(bar).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

But it turns out this test passes perfectly even without this tweak and if I add a print in the factory function I can see it is called only once.

**Can somebody explain to me what's the exact behavior of the factory function?**